Overlay text when using geom_text and facet_wrap in R
I'm having some trouble with the geom_text combined in facet_wrap function in RStudio.
I wanted to insert the R^2 of each function in each graph created with the ggplot2 library.
I've summyrised the R^2 of each function in a dataframe using the following code:
df_R_DENSITY<-data.frame(Trial=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","L"),
                   R = c("italic(R^2) == 0.865", "italic(R^2) == 0.908", "italic(R^2) == 0.887",    "italic(R^2) == 0.890", "italic(R^2) == 0.854", "italic(R^2) == 0.825", "italic(R^2) == 0.895", "italic(R^2) == 0.926", "italic(R^2) == 0.864", "italic(R^2) == 0.798"))

I then created the graph using the following code:
ggplot()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 25, size=0.5, alpha = 0.6, color="gold2") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 35, size=0.5, alpha = 0.6, color="cyan3") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 60, size=0.5, alpha = 0.6, color="magenta") +
  geom_point(data = df,aes(x=MetriCorrectetd,y=Droplets.cm2), size=0.2, colour="blue")+
  geom_line(data = DF_Predicted_Density,aes(x=MetriCorrectetd,y = Predicted), size=0.8,  colour = "green3", alpha = 0.8)+
  facet_wrap(~ LABEL, ncol=2)+
  geom_text(x = 4.5, y = 225, aes(label = R), data = df_R_DENSITY, parse = T, hjust = 0)+
 ylim(0,250)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 24), 
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        strip.background=element_rect(fill="coral2"))

But the R^2 are superimposed on each other in each facet of the graph. As you can see in the picture.
How can I solve this problem?

It looks like df_R_DENSITY needs a LABEL column so that the data can be mapped to the facets.

It is not possible to reproduce your question as we don't have access to DF_Predicted_Density. Please see here how to use a minimal reproducible example. Nevertheless, you can add R2 using stat_cor(...) from the ggpubr package.
Also see this similar SO question
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~manufacturer) +
  stat_cor(aes(label = after_stat(rr.label)), color = "black", geom = "text")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.1.0
